# Sonar: "Close this PreparedStatement"

Tags: java, sonarqube

Why is [SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/) plugin for Jenkins complaining about the open statement if I close it in the finally block?

(I need to validate database connections in a separate function.)

```
final String PING = "SELECT 1 from dual";

public boolean validateConnection(Connection conn) { 

    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    try{
        if(conn == null){
            LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, "Null connection on PING. Reached max # of connections or network issue. Stats: "+getCacheStatistics() );
            return false;
        }

        if(conn.isClosed()){
            // logger
            return false;   
        } 

        statement = conn.prepareStatement( PING ); //%%%%%% SONAR: Close this "PreparedStatement".
        statement.setQueryTimeout(QUERY_TIMEOUT);

        try( ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery() ){
            if ( rs != null && rs.next() ) {
                return true;
            }
        }catch(Exception exRs){
            // logger
            throw exRs;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        // logger
    }finally{
        try{
            statement.close();
        }catch(Exception excpt){
            // logger
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The way you updated your code will run into null pointer exceptions if conn is null or closed.

Comment: Right.. but I've removed "if(statement!=null)" before closing the statement just because sonar complains that that condition would have always been true..

Comment: @TT. I have not clear the reason for the downvote, could you please clarify? thanks

Comment: I'm the only one that gave you an **upvote**, two **other** people have downvoted. I cannot speak for other people.

Comment: I don't use SonarQube, but I'd say: start using [`try-with-resources`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html) (requires Java 1.7+). Maybe that'll shut SonarQube up. Also, why have the checks on `conn` inside that try-block? Move them outside that block.

Comment: @TT. Yep I'm already using try-with-resource for the resultset. I'll update my code using it for the statement too, thanks. About the try block instead Connection.isClosed() could throw SQLException and the logger too (question updated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've refactored my code in this way as suggested by @TT and sonar **stopped complaining**.

```
public boolean validateConnection(Connection conn) {

    LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingConn );

    try{

        if(conn == null){
            LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, "Null connection on PING. Reached max # of connections or network issue. Stats: "+getCacheStatistics() );
            return false;
        }

        if(conn.isClosed()){
            LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, "Found closed connection during validation PING." );
            return false;   
        } 

        try( PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement( PING ) ){

             statement.setQueryTimeout(QUERY_TIMEOUT);

             try( ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery() ){

                if ( rs != null && rs.next() ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, ex );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Without "try-with-resource" the code could be refactored in the following way but in this case Sonar **still complains**:

```
public boolean validateConnection(Connection conn) {

    LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingConn );

    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{

        if(conn == null){
            LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, "Null connection on PING. Reached max # of connections or network issue. Stats: "+getCacheStatistics() );
            return false;
        }

        if(conn.isClosed()){
            LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, "Found closed connection during validation PING." );
            return false;   
        } 

        statement = conn.prepareStatement( PING );
        statement.setQueryTimeout( QUERY_TIMEOUT );
        rs = statement.executeQuery();

        if ( rs != null && rs.next() ) {
            return true;
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, ex );
    }finally{
        try {
            if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException eClosing1) {
            LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, eClosing1 );
        }finally{
            try {
                if(statement!=null){
                    statement.close();
                }
            }catch (SQLException eClosing2) {
                LOGGER.log( LogEntries.PingError, eClosing2 );
            }   
        }
     }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I donnot see the point of putting all this nested `try` blocks with no `catch`.
You need only the first `try` with the suitable `catch` and `finally` where you close your `statment`s and `connection` after checking them against `null`.

Comment: It's the try-with-resources approach (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html).
The idea behind the code in my question was to use different LogEntries with distinct severity but Sonar oddly complained about an unclosed statement. I've updated my answer adding also your solution but Sonar still complains with your approach.